# Is it normal to have 40% capacity after 1.5 years of charging Li-Ion?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, capacity

I have a laptop computer that spends 99% of its time plugged in. The last time prior to today I used the computer not plugged in was 1.5 years ago.

Today morning, I put the computer to sleep (with its battery capacity at 95%), went to work with the laptop in my bag, and started to use the laptop after 4 hours of sleep not plugged in. I was surprised to see the battery capacity was at 40%!

Then I used the computer plugged in for few hours, put it to sleep, put the computer to my bag, and after 4 hours of sleep in my bag turned it back on. Now battery capacity was at 100%.

So, it appears if you charge a lithium-ion battery for a really long amount of time such as 1.5 years, its actual capacity can be 40% whereas the displayed capacity is at 95%.

My question is: is this normal?

And before you ask, the full charge capacity has went from 46642 mWh to 44084 mWh, i.e. very minimal decrease.

Answer (score 2):

Battery gauges often don't work well with aged batteries, so the state of charge you are reading can be pretty inaccurate.

Also, the ideal state of charge for long battery lifetime (obviously not runtime)  is around 50% charge.  If you leave it plugged in all of the time at 100% charge you will reduce the useful life of the battery.

Some laptop manufacturers have a mode that only charges to 50% if you intend to plug it in for long periods.

Answer (score 0):

According to battery-testing firm Cadex Electronics, a fully charged lithium-ion battery will lose about 20 percent of its capacity after a year of typical storage. Increase the storage temperature to just above 100 degrees Fahrenheit such as in a hot attic for example and that number increases to 35 percent. So the environment it is stored in is a factor as well.

As John D mentioned leaving the battery at 100% charge will cause it to degrade faster.

Individual Lithium Ion cells should never be discharged below 3volts or charged above 4.2volts.  Ideally they should be stored at 3.7volts to maximize their life.